AWS Textract: stop rotating image
I want to analyze a document that has vertical and horizontal text. I tried rotating the image 90 degrees before sending it to AWS Textract, but it appears the backend automatically "corrects" the orientation before extracting text. Is there a way to block this behavior?
import boto3
from PIL import Image

textract = boto3.client('textract')

# Analyze original image
with open('example.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    response = textract.detect_document_text(Document={'Bytes': f.read()})
[block['Text'] for block in response['Blocks'] if block['BlockType'] == 'LINE']
['Most text is horizontal', "Here's another horizontal line"] # capturing horizontal text

# Rotate image 90 degrees
image = Image.open('example.jpg')
image = image.rotate(-90)
image.save('example_rotated.jpg')

# Analyze rotated image
with open('example_rotated.jpg', 'rb') as f:
    response = textract.detect_document_text(Document={'Bytes': f.read()})
[block['Text'] for block in response['Blocks'] if block['BlockType'] == 'LINE']
['Most text is horizontal', "Here's another horizontal line"] # still capturing horizontal text

example.jpg

